# Using R's tryCatch

Tags: r, try-catch

Trying to use `R`'s `tryCatch` on fitting a log-logistic curve to a dose-response data:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c(10,0.62,2.5,0.16,0.039,0.0024,0.0098,0.00061,10,0.62,2.5,0.16,0.039,0.0024,0.0098,0.00061,10,0.62,2.5,0.16,0.039,0.0024,0.0098,0.00061),
                 viability=c(22,79,100,61,100,87,75,51,6.5,37,100,100,90,100,42,41,5,100,13,100,91,100,95,100),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

with `drc`'s `drm` function using this code:

```
library(drc)
fit <- tryCatch(
  {
    drm(viability~dose,data=df,fct=LL.4(names=c("slope","low","high","ED50")))
  },
  error=function(cond){
    return(NA)
  },
  warning=function(cond){
    return(NA)
  },
  finally={  
  }
)
```

I get:

```
> fit
[1] NA
```

However, when I try without `tryCatch` there's no problem:

```
> drm(viability~dose,data=df,fct=LL.4(names=c("slope","low","high","ED50")))

A 'drc' model.

Call:
drm(formula = viability ~ dose, data = df, fct = LL.4(names = c("slope",     "low", "high", "ED50")))

Coefficients:
slope:(Intercept)    low:(Intercept)   high:(Intercept)   ED50:(Intercept)  
            1.498           -163.577             81.031             18.481
```

Am I not using `tryCatch` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `tryCatch` correctly. Your code is throwing a warning. I modified your code to return the error or warning message:

```
fit <- tryCatch(
  {
    drm(viability~dose,data=df,fct=LL.4(names=c("slope","low","high","ED50")))
  },
  error=function(cond){
    return(cond)
  },
  warning=function(cond){
    return(cond)
  },
  finally={  
  }
)
```

And now running `fit` reveals that `drm` is throwing a warning:

```
> fit
<simpleWarning in log(dose/parmMat[, 4]): NaNs produced>
```